# jQuery function VS Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function

What are the differences, and which is better ?

```
(function($){
    $.random = function(){
        alert('random');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
function random() {
    alert('random');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'Better' for what? And the first is an immediately-invoked JavaScript function, and the latter is 'just' a JavaScript function. What is it that you're trying to ask about?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library. There is no such thing as a jQuery function.

Comment: The difference is just whether `random` is associated with `jQuery` or not. As for "*better*," does `random` benefit from or depend on that association? If "*yes*," 1st. Otherwise, 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample :

```
(function($){
    $.random = function(){
        alert('random');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Is the same as :

```
jQuery.random = function(){
    alert('random');
};
```

And this sample :

```
function random() {
    alert('random');
}
```

Is the same as :

```
window.random = function() {
    alert('random');
};
```

As you can see, the only difference is the namespace (`jQuery` and `window`) :

```
jQuery.random = function() { alert('random'); };
window.random = function() { alert('random'); };
```

Answer (score 2):

The first example:

- Doesn't use any features of jQuery
- Depends on jQuery
- Uses more code

"Better" is rather subjective, but I can't see any benefits of that approach for this code.

Comment: I'm sorry but the third point is wrong.

Comment: Good point. I'm so used to seeing jQuery's horribly overloaded `$(function () {})` syntax that I misread it as that, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions does the exact same thing so there is no difference in functionality.

The first syntax would be better because it doesn't bloat the global namespace with another function, but instead adds that function to jQuery, but that's not the right way to extend jQuery though.